# I want to be applied paintComponent individually

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I make a PaintBrush.
I want to apply the line in a different color, but all the lines change to the same color.
I painted it white to create the eraser function, and when I use the eraser, all the lines become white, and when I select a different color, the lines reappear with the color I chose.

```
//choose the color
public void ColorBox() {
        ArrayList<Color> clist = new ArrayList<>();
        clist.add(Color.RED);
        clist.add(Color.ORANGE);
        clist.add(Color.YELLOW);
        clist.add(Color.GREEN);
        clist.add(Color.BLUE);
        clist.add(Color.MAGENTA);
        clist.add(Color.WHITE);
        clist.add(Color.BLACK);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < clist.size(); i++) {
            JButton cbutton = new JButton();
            cbutton.setBackground(clist.get(i));
            cbutton.setBounds(500+50*i, 10, 37, 37); add(cbutton);
            cbutton.addActionListener(e -> {
                colour = cbutton.getBackground();
            });
            add(cbutton);
        }
    }
```

```
    public void Pencil() {
        JButton pen = new JButton(new ImageIcon("icon\\pencil.png"));
        pen.setBounds(200, 10, 37, 37); add(pen);
        pen.addActionListener(e -> {
            draw = true; erase = false;
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    super.mouseDragged(e);
                    x = e.getX();
                    y = e.getY();
                    plist.add(new Point(x, y));
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        });
    }
    
    public void Eraser() {
        JButton eraser = new JButton(new ImageIcon("icon\\eraser.png"));
        eraser.setBounds(250, 10, 37, 37); add(eraser);
        eraser.addActionListener(e -> {
            draw = false; erase = true;
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    super.mouseDragged(e);
                    x = e.getX();
                    y = e.getY();
                    elist.add(new Point(x, y));
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (draw == true)
            g.setColor(colour);
            for (Point p : plist) {
                g.fillOval(p.x, p.y, 5, 5);
            }
        if (erase == true)
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            for (Point p : plist) {
                g.fillOval(p.x, p.y, 5, 5);
            }
    }
```

Full Code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Point {
    int x, y;
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

class Board extends JPanel {
    int x, y;
    Color colour;
    boolean draw = false; boolean erase = false;
    Vector<Point> plist = new Vector<>();
    Vector<Point> elist = new Vector<>();
    public void ColorBox() {
        ArrayList<Color> clist = new ArrayList<>();
        clist.add(Color.RED);
        clist.add(Color.ORANGE);
        clist.add(Color.YELLOW);
        clist.add(Color.GREEN);
        clist.add(Color.BLUE);
        clist.add(Color.MAGENTA);
        clist.add(Color.WHITE);
        clist.add(Color.BLACK);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < clist.size(); i++) {
            JButton cbutton = new JButton();
            cbutton.setBackground(clist.get(i));
            cbutton.setBounds(500+50*i, 10, 37, 37); add(cbutton);
            cbutton.addActionListener(e -> {
                colour = cbutton.getBackground();
            });
            add(cbutton);
        }
    }
    
    public void Pencil() {
        JButton pen = new JButton(new ImageIcon("icon\\pencil.png"));
        pen.setBounds(200, 10, 37, 37); add(pen);
        pen.addActionListener(e -> {
            draw = true; erase = false;
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    super.mouseDragged(e);
                    x = e.getX();
                    y = e.getY();
                    plist.add(new Point(x, y));
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        });
    }
    
    public void Eraser() {
        JButton eraser = new JButton(new ImageIcon("icon\\eraser.png"));
        eraser.setBounds(250, 10, 37, 37); add(eraser);
        eraser.addActionListener(e -> {
            draw = false; erase = true;
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    super.mouseDragged(e);
                    x = e.getX();
                    y = e.getY();
                    elist.add(new Point(x, y));
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (draw == true)
            g.setColor(colour);
            for (Point p : plist) {
                g.fillOval(p.x, p.y, 5, 5);
            }
        if (erase == true)
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            for (Point p : plist) {
                g.fillOval(p.x, p.y, 5, 5);
            }
    }
    public Board() {
        setLayout(null);
        this.Pencil();
        this.Eraser();
        this.ColorBox();
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }
}

public class PaintBrush extends JFrame {
    
    public PaintBrush() {
        setSize(1200, 600);
        setTitle("그림판");
        add(new Board());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PaintBrush p = new PaintBrush();
    }

}
```

How can I do?

Comment: You have to either draw to an offscreen buffer and paint that to the component or keep track of everything that has been painted along with its color and paint them all.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.  Don't provide snippets of code that are missing value (e.g. you are overriding `paintComponent` but I see no `JPanel` or `JComponent`.

Comment: Create a new "drawing" entity, which can hold the x/y points and color to be used.  This is what gets added to the `List`

Comment: Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for working examples of the two approaches suggested in the above comments.

Comment: Java/Swing/AWT already has a `Point` class, might want to use it ;)

Answer (score 1):

So, the basic idea is, you need to keep track of the color each "pixel" is meant to be painted with.

I'd start by creating some kind of "drawing" entity to track this, for example...

```
public class Pixel {
    private Point point;
    private Color color;

    public Pixel(Point point, Color color) {
        this.point = point;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Point getPoint() {
        return point;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

When the user selects a color, you apply it to an instance field and when the user drags the mouse, you create a new instance of `Pixel` with the selected color, for example...

```
int x = e.getX();
int y = e.getY();

Pixel pixel = new Pixel(e.getPoint(), getPixelColor());
pixels.add(pixel);
repaint();
```

## Runnable example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;

public final class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MainPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Pixel {
        private Point point;
        private Color color;

        public Pixel(Point point, Color color) {
            this.point = point;
            this.color = color;
        }

        public Point getPoint() {
            return point;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }
    }

    public class MainPane extends JPanel {

        private CanvasPane canvasPane;

        public MainPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            canvasPane = new CanvasPane();
            add(canvasPane);

            Color[] colors = new Color[]{
                Color.RED,
                Color.ORANGE,
                Color.YELLOW,
                Color.GREEN,
                Color.BLUE,
                Color.MAGENTA,
                Color.WHITE,
                Color.BLACK
            };
            JPanel colorSelectionPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
            for (Color color : colors) {
                JToggleButton btn = new JToggleButton();
                btn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
                btn.setBorderPainted(false);
                btn.setForeground(color);
                btn.setBackground(color);
                btn.setOpaque(true);
                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        canvasPane.setPixelColor(color);
                    }
                });

                colorSelectionPane.add(btn, gbc);
                bg.add(btn);
            }
            add(colorSelectionPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        }
    }

    public class CanvasPane extends JPanel {

        private List<Pixel> pixels = new ArrayList<>(128);
        private Color pixelColor = Color.BLACK;

        public CanvasPane() {
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    int x = e.getX();
                    int y = e.getY();

                    Pixel pixel = new Pixel(e.getPoint(), getPixelColor());
                    pixels.add(pixel);
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        public Color getPixelColor() {
            return pixelColor;
        }

        public void setPixelColor(Color pixelColor) {
            this.pixelColor = pixelColor;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            for (Pixel pixel : pixels) {
                g2d.setColor(pixel.getColor());
                Point p = pixel.getPoint();
                g2d.fillOval(p.x - 2, p.y - 2, 4, 4);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

## Feedback...

This (and the eraser work flow)...

```
pen.addActionListener(e -> {
    draw = true; erase = false;
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseDragged(e);
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
            plist.add(new Point(x, y));
            repaint();
        }
    });
});
```

is a bad idea.  Every time you action either of these two, you are adding ANOTHER mouse listener, this is going to be become messy very quickly.

I would, personally, make a simple `enum` with `DRAW` and `ERASE` and maintain a simple instance field which described the current "pen action".

When erasing, instead of drawing "white" pixels, I would use a "collision detection" workflow and remove the pixels from the `List` if you run over them, but that's me.